# linked to not working in donut chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart, donut-chart

I have donut chart in highcharts, It has two concentric circles. Inner circle represents browser data and outer circle shows distributions of that segment into different versions.

I want outer slice to be toggled along with inner slice when I toggle a legend. Which is not happening currently. I have tried `linkedTo` property but it's not working too. Please help.

Here is a fiddle for problem [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ds2r4nxr/)

Comment: See the same topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642139/highcharts-donut-legend-toggle/17653244#17653244